# Java generic function that uses a switch to return value

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error fragment already defined on the line where i'm instantiating the Search Fragment. What am I doing wrong?

```
private <T extends Fragment> T getInitialFragment(Tab clickedTab) {
        switch (clickedTab) {
            case TAB_A:
                ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
                return (T)fragment;
            case TAB_B:
                SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
                return (T)fragment;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Add the error message. It may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same name for different variables if they share the scope - you have variables named `fragment` declared twice in your code. You cannot have it, so rename i.e. one to `fragmentList` second to `fragmentSearch` or ditch the assignment completely as there's no benefit:

```
private <T extends Fragment> T getInitialFragment(Tab clickedTab) {

        switch (clickedTab) {
            case TAB_A:
                return (T)(new ListFragment());
            case TAB_B:
                return (T)(new SearchFragment());
        }

 }
```

you should also add `default` to your `switch`.

Comment: But SearchFragment isn't of the same class as ListFragment, so that won't work

Comment: Indeed, missed that. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because switch-case is fall-trough (all cases are visited until a break/return is found) all cases have the same scope. Either rename the second fragment to fragment2 or define it in the outer scope as T fragment;

Edit: to late.